# JIRA github smartcommit

Tags: github, jira, smart-commits

I am not able to transition any issue or update their state from github state.

I tried following commands :-

```
git commit -m "NDA-113 #time 1w 2d 4h 30m Total work logged"
git commit -m "NDA-113 #comment Total work logged"
```

Those commits are coming in development section but smart commit actions are not working.

I tried all the suggestion in Atlassian docs, user email in JIRA and github account is same.

Answer (score 0):

Check what you email on github are same in jira

Answer (score 0):

If your email is the same (which catch me out as my IntelliJ was adjusting my email on commits), then the next most likely cause is that you haven't setup [Transition Triggers](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/configuring-workflow-triggers-802592811.html) in your workflow and/or are not calling it in the commit.

*Example:*

git commit -m "NDA-113 **#qa** #comment Total work logged"

Where the #qa is the transition to QA lane

Final Note: For sanity double check that you have [Switched On Smart Commits](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/enabling-smart-commits-298976933.html)